# Piecewise linear optimization with resource allocation constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming

I have this problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{w}} & \sum_{i=1}^N c_i P_i(w_i)\\
s.t & \notag\\
 & \sum_{i =1 }^N w_i = w \\
 & 0 \leq w_i \leq w_{max},~~\forall i \in 1, ..., N 
\end{align}

where $P_i(w)$ is a piecewise linear convex function. Is there a closed formula to solve this? If not, what is the most relevant algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $P_i(w)$ is a piecewise linear, convex function, then it can be written as the maximum of a number of linear functions, $P_i(w)=\max \{L_{i1}(w),\ldots,L_{iJ_i}(w)\}$. Then, the optimization problem allows for the reformulation
$$
  \min_{\mathbf w,\mathbf x} \sum_{i=1}^N c_ix_i = \mathbf c^T \mathbf x, \\
  \sum_{i=1}^N w_i = w \\
  0\le w_i \le w_{max}, \qquad i=1,\ldots,N \\
  x_i \ge L_{ij}(w) \qquad j=1,\ldots,J_i.
$$
This is a linear program with linear constraints that can be solved using, for example, the simplex algorithm. There is, in general, no closed-form solution, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have come to the same conclusion myself.